# get all table's name and its disk size in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Am using [pg_relation_size](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT) function to get size of a particular table in my *PostgreSQL 9.2*  database.

for example,

```
select pg_relation_size('public.tbl_tras_log')
```

will return the size of `tbl_tras_log`.

---

So, My question is how can I get *size* of all *tables* in a *database* ?

Comment: Check this link may be it will be helpful to your question.......   http://www.niwi.be/2013/02/17/postgresql-database-table-indexes-size/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its better to use [pg_size_pretty - Converts a size in bytes expressed as a 64-bit integer into a human-readable format with size units](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT)

for example

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('public.audit_14'))
```

> Result : 1624 kB

and the answer for your question is,

```
select 
    schemaname,
    relname as table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(schemaname ||'.'||relname)) as table_size 
from 
(
  select 
      schemaname, 
      relname 
  from pg_stat_user_tables order by relname 
) t
```

Comment: Thanks for the very useful answer! Helped me a lot. I did have some issues with capitalized table names (resulting in "relation does not exist" errors), that was solved by changing the 4th line to: pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('\"' || schemaname || '\".\"' || relname || '\"')) as table_size_pretty (just in case some one else also struggles with this...)

Comment: Thank you very much.  order by n_live_tup better for me.

Answer (score 0):

To not have the

> capitalized table names (resulting in "relation does not exist" errors),

you can use the `quote_ident` function, so the full example:

```sql
select 
    schemaname,
    relname as table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(schemaname) ||'.'|| quote_ident(relname)))) as table_size 
from 
(
  select 
      schemaname, 
      relname 
  from pg_stat_user_tables order by relname 
) t
```